# Display data from database without using form tags?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a search form where the user will insert his/her CODE and NAME & TELEPHONE of that CODE will then be shown inside a table which is working fine (Thanks to stack overflow).

```
<form action="list25.php" method="post">
  Search By code:<input type="text" name="code"><br><br>


  <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="product-table">
      <tr>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="">Name</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="">telephone</a></th>
      </tr>
      <?php
      if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $code = $_POST['code'];
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sahmiye");
        $query = "select * from balance where code = $code  ";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['telephone']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
      }
    } else {
      echo "Undifined ID";
      $name = "";
      $telephone = "";
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($connect);
  } else {
    $name = "";
    $telephone = "";
  }
  ?>
  </table> 
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find">                
</form>
```

BUT i have a second completely different form as well and when the user writes his/her CODE in this second form i needed the NAME & TELEPHONE of that CODE to then be shown  inside textboxes and the user will then fill up the rest of the form and then submit it so it can be saved into the database.

The problem being i know i cant have a form within a form but  is there a way for me to run my first  search form shown above with out using a form so that i can have the same function inside my second form whereby after CODE is given , it will fill up the textboxes with the NAME & TELEPHONE of that CODE ?

Comment: What is the datatype of field `code` ??

Comment: the datatype is varchar

Comment: you need quotes around $code as `code = '$code'` . Better use prepare statement!!

Comment: @thebigO if you tend to ask a question, get help and just leave without selecting and thanking those who help, then you will find it harder to get help next time.

Comment: the code above is working fine but i needed the same functionality for my second form but i cant have a form within a form the functionality being when the  CODE textbox is given the NAME & TELEPHONE textbox fields are automatically filled up in this second  form and afterwards i can submit my form.

Comment: I posted an answer almost an hour ago yet didn't get any feedback from you @thebigO If that didn't work for you, then you will need to let me know and to elaborate on your question; it's tad unclear/complicated.

Comment: it's been a long day, thanks for your answer appreciate it a lot  Fred -ii-,, i diddn't know about the accepting of answer since am new here and this was my second question that i have posted so thanks for that as well.

Comment: @thebigO You're most welcome and welcome to Stack, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Display data from database without using form tags?*

You need to use a GET array and use the parameter in the `href`.

I.e. and checking if it is set and not empty and equal to "something":

```
<a href="file.php?var=John">Name</a>
```

Then use the GET array with the parameter.

```
if(!empty($_GET['var']) && $_GET['var'] == 'John'){

    // do your thing to search for the string "John", as an example.
    // ATT'N: John and john in the database are two different animals.

}
```

Use the same format for the other `href`.

Sidenote: Remove the `href`'s from inside the `<form></form>` tags, as it *may* cause some havoc.

You will also need to quote the variable in the query when it is a string.

I.e.:

```
$query = "select * from balance where code = '$code'  ";
```

...if `$code` is a string.

However, it will throw an error if the query contains characters that MySQL will complain about such as `John's Bar & Grill`, therefore a prepared statement/escaping the value will be required and will help prevent a possible SQL injection at the same time.

Reference:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

---

**Edit:**

Going over the question again and TBH is a bit complicated, using sessions would be something to use in order to keep the values.

- http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

...then checking if any of the session array(s) is/are set and not empty.

- **N.B.:** `session_start();` must reside inside all pages using sessions in order for this to work. Inputs can also contain sessions-related code and "if set/not empty". Otherwise, you will get errors about them being undefined.